# changing object type in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, user-defined-types

I am changing the type of an Oracle user defined 'type'. I am adding an attribute to the type. This type hass been used in several places. How can I chcek if any part of the code will be affected by the addition of an attribute to the type. Or what are the scenarios where the addition of an attribute will cause an issue.

Comment: which version of the database are you using?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what are the dependencies to this user defined type and how you have used the type inside the procedure or other objects. You have to find all the dependencies and revisit them to make sure the changes you make to the type will be invoked inside the object without any trouble.